# how to run my service once in 30 minutes?

Tags: android, background-service

Can any body say me a simple way to run an service once in half an hour?

this is not atall working can any body say how to run it once in half an hour pls.

i use this for start my app on system boot even that is not working..?

i am doing this :

autostart.java

```
public class autostart extends BroadcastReceiver 
{
    public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) 
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(arg0,back_process.class);
        arg0.startService(intent);
        Log.i("Autostart", "started");
    }
}
```

Back_Process.java

```
 public class gps_back_process extends Service
    {
        private static final String TAG = "MyService";
        @Override
        public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
            return null;
        }
        public void onDestroy() {

            Toast.makeText(this, "SERVICE STOPPED ..!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Log.d(TAG, "onDestroy");
        }

        @Override
        public void onStart(Intent intent, int startid)
        {
            Intent intents = new Intent(getBaseContext(),MainActivity.class);
            intents.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(intents);
            Toast.makeText(this, "SERVICE STARTED", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Log.d(TAG, "onStart");
        }
    }
```

Thank you!

Comment: have you added permission for system boot completed in your manifest...

Comment: use of pandding intent for 30 minute after call service or Runnable

Comment: yes added all permissions even not working

Comment: If the user never starts your app explicitly (by launching an `Intent`), your application will remain in the "stopped state" and it will **not get the BOOT_COMPLETED broadcast**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
private AlarmManager alarmMgr;
private PendingIntent alarmIntent;

alarmMgr = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);

alarmMgr.set(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP,
        SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() +
        60 * 1000, alarmIntent);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) and its method `setRepeating()`. Some time ago I asked [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12125537/everyday-notifications-at-certain-time). My interval was 24h, but with yours 0,5h it's the same story.