# How to force an application to stay open?

Tags: java, android, memory

I have seen apps like Lookout, JuiceDefender, and MagicJack run in the background indefinitely, unless force closed by a user directly through the task manager. (And even then, in Gingerbread, it wouldn't close unless you browsed to the application that was running under "Downloaded Apps" in the settings and force closed it once you were at the menu where you have options to manage the app like "Clear Memory" and "Force Close".

I am wondering how this is accomplished? I need to do something similar for an app of mine but I don't know how to avoid the Android OS's automatic task killing.. And don't say it's not possible because if that were true, JuiceDefender, MagicJack, and Lookout would not work.

Comment: You'd better have a good reason for this.  And by good reason I mean a "kittens will die if this doesn't happen" kind of reason.  I detest applications that take control of my own device away from me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can have is a service that stays alive indefinitely. You achieve that returning Service.START_STICKY on your Service's onStartCommand method.

Whenever the os needs resources and chooses to kill your app, your service will be respawned as soon as the resources are available again.

Bear in mind that having an application that is continuously alive will result in consuming the phone's battery. You should (at least) notify the user with a notification that your app is still alive in the background.

On top of that, you can [register a broadcast receiver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5290141/android-broadcastreceiver-on-startup#) for the BOOT_COMPLETED event in order to restart your service while the device gets restarted. Yet, bear in mind that this could result in eating the phone's battery and so be careful on what you are doing in the service.

Answer (score 1):

I believe these apps are launching a [`Service`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html) when their Activity get started (i.e when [`onCreate()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onCreate%28android.os.Bundle%29) is called).

A `Service` keeps running when the application get paused. When the `Service` is launched, you may return *`START_STICKY`* in your `onStartCommand`.

Also, to prevent a Service from being killed by Android's memory killer, you can specify that your Service is important to the user by calling [`startForeground()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#startForeground%28int,%20android.app.Notification%29). Android Developers website states that :

> A foreground service is a service that's considered to be something
>   the user is actively aware of and thus not a candidate for the system
>   to kill when low on memory.

Answer (score 0):

I am creating an app and I have to use one or more of the following super functions inside OnCreate():

```
onDestroy()
onPause()
onResume()
onSaveInstanceState()
```

to close an app completely from the memory. And also do not use Activity.finish() method. Usually Android does a pretty good job in closing the app when memory is needed, called pop out of stack and not recommended to forcefully stay in memory, unless there is a very very good reason to. Hope it helps.
You can also check the Android DOC website for more information and examples to your request.

Answer (score 0):

You need to start a service. Services runs in background and is useful to push alerts. 
This some links about it:

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html
http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidServices/article.html

Answer (score 0):

In the service onStartCommand method return "START_STICKY".

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html

/Thomas