# How to keep a Android app always running (Service and BroadcastReceiver)?

Tags: java, android, service, broadcastreceiver

I realized an android application which always has to remain activated in the background. To make that, it is enough to use a Service which remains active after the user is left the application.

Nevertheless, if the user rebooting, the application as well as the Service will not be any more active.

**How to solve this problem?**

I think of having an idea with **[BroadcastReceiver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5290164/1832221)** but I am not on whether it is the best solution.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: yes @StinePike, sorry for my English!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you want the service to restart if the phone is rebooted ?

Create a BroadcastReceiver that listens for `BOOT_COMPLETE` (you need a permission for this).  Have it start your service.

Android may stop your service due to lack of memory.If you have onStartCommand return `START_STICKY` and have your onCreate of the service call startService on itself, you'll restart when memory is available.

Comment: Detailed description with examples, found it really useful [https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Starting-Background-Services](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Starting-Background-Services)

Answer (score 0):

You can set up an alarm to wake your service if its not running, and set up a broadcast receiver on boot which will start the service when the device boot.