# How to start service on device boot and on application start

Tags: android, service, boot

I need service, which will be started on device boot, also I need to start that service if user start application manually.

This service have to be alive on background, even if user kill application with Task Killer, etc.

Any answer is apprecitiated.

Comment: Try to check this [answer][1] !!
I hope it helps

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784441/trying-to-start-a-service-on-boot-on-android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get a callback when the device starts, check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5290141/android-broadcastreceiver-on-startup).

Start a Service in [foreground](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#startForeground%28int,%20android.app.Notification%29) if you want it to survive even when the device is low on memory. Read more on [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html).