# how to make our app to start automatically?

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I have an apk which runs only on background. I want it to start itself every X seconds.

I can do it from terminal with sh command:

```
#!/bin/bash
while true
do am start --user 0 -a android.intent.action.MAIN -n com.xxxxxxx/.MainActivity
sleep 20
done
```

But after reboot it stops running itself automatically. Besides, I don't want to use sh command everytime. So I decompiled the apk with apktool. What do I need to add to make our app start it self every x seconds?

p.s. I know that if I save the commands as sh file into etc/init.d/ it'll be persistent but I'm trying to learn how can we add it to source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What do I need to add to make our app start it self every x seconds?

You need to schedule it with the [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html). You can find more about that [here](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html).

> But after reboot it stops running itself automatically.

You need to register a receiver for `android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED` for you app to be invoked after boot. You can find an answer for that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5290141/android-broadcastreceiver-on-startup). When your receiver is invoked, you can then again schedule your app for restarting.