# How to get the first boot time of an android device?

Tags: android, boot

Is there any possibility to know the below:

- When was the android device first started-date or time
- Device's first boot time

Answer (score 3):

Simple, if you use your Android mobile phone with your google account. (For syncing contacts, photos, etc) Simply go to https://myaccount.google.com/device-activity
There you should see your current mobile phone and maybe other devices. Click on "More Information" at your mobile phone - and there you see the date of your first Google login with this device, when you first booted and configured it.

Answer (score 0):

Not unless your APK is installed on the device at first boot.

Comment: Yes the apk will be installed

Comment: Maybe you can use something like this then: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5290141/android-broadcastreceiver-on-startup

Comment: That's not what I want. Ii want the device's first boot time. That is when the device is purchased and it is booted the first time by an end user.

Comment: If you have an APK preinstalled receiving the boot intent you can register it yourself? You won't get it from the device.

Comment: I would be having pre installed app.

Comment: Ok, then you can use the link i pasted above, register for BOOT_COMPLETED and record the time with your app.