# detect if device rebooted between two application use or not

Tags: java, android

**In nutshell, I need to detect if device rebooted between two application use or not.**

**Here is why I need that:** I create an app and I need to know the reliable `date and time` and save tasks with that date and time into device database and after while, sync that data. Also it is important that users can use this app while offline. I tried many things, even try to use `NITZ` but no one works for me.

So I end up with this scenario:

1. When user want to save a task, I get the server time and save it with device boot time ( From [elapsedRealTime()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/SystemClock.html#elapsedRealtime()) )
2. After that when user want to save a task, I can find the reliable time with compare two boot time value and add the difference to saved server time
3. If user reboot the device, I need to repeat step 1

I mean in each boot, I need to get server time once. For this I need to know if device rebooted or not and I have no idea how to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5290141/android-broadcastreceiver-on-startup) question, on how you can create a receiver to catch the BOOT_COMPLETED event.