# Notifications android going away not working

Tags: java, android

I am using the alarm builder currently for setting notifications for my users in period of 1 day and 4 hours.. but if they turn off there phone then the notifications go away. How do i do notifcations where the system wont delete them. If you have an answer to share with me or a tutorial to fixing my issue that would be great.

Comment: have written any code yet ? please share some code.

Comment: My code doesnt work it has flaws and described above. Im looking for a new solution that someone can share with me

Comment: you can use onbootcomplete receiver to when device is on and again show the pending notification because you cant start device programmatically.

Comment: Is that a permission i would have to add? I want to keep the permissions little as possible.. also can you share code example

Comment: look at this post and implement boot receiver  if you want yes this requires permission and as far as i know you cannot start the android device at time of your alarm notification so have to show the pending notification when the device restarts and also don't ask for code your question may be put down implement your self if you face problem then post code and ask for answer for the issue.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5290141/android-broadcastreceiver-on-startup