# How to keep alarms after device was restarted

Tags: android

I wanna make simple alarm clock. And I know that after restarting all my alarms will be cleared. How can I keep all alarms after device was restarted? 
This is how I set alarm:

```
Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        final TimePicker timePicker1 = (TimePicker) findViewById(R.id.timePicker1);
        final Intent intent1 = new Intent(MainActivity.this,myReceiver.class);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Calendar calendar1 = Calendar.getInstance();
                calendar1.set(Calendar.MINUTE, timePicker1.getCurrentMinute());
                calendar1.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,timePicker1.getCurrentHour());
                AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
                PendingIntent pi1 =PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainActivity2.this,0,intent1,0);
                am.set(AlarmManager.RTC,calendar1.getTimeInMillis(),pi1);
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Save the alarms you want to have and create a receiver that sets them all at boot.

[Android BroadcastReceiver on startup - keep running when Activity is in Background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5290141/android-broadcastreceiver-on-startup)

Comment: @se-bastiaan Can you please tell me how can I save them?

Comment: Depending on how many alarms you have: a sqlite database or sharedpreferences