# how to show notification when app is not running

Tags: android

My Scenario is to show Greeting notification to my users even they are not using the app. Below code is working fine if the open is opened or minimized. But, I want to show the notification in morning even though the user did not open the application.

Main Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private PendingIntent pendingIntent;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 18);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 40);
        calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MyReceiver.class);
        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainActivity.this, 0, myIntent,0);

        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);

    } //end onCreate
}
```

My Receiver Class:

```
public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        /*Intent service1 = new Intent(context, MyAlarmService.class);
         context.startService(service1);*/
        try{
            Utils.generateNotification(context);
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Utils  Class:

```
public class Utils {

    public static NotificationManager mManager;

    @SuppressWarnings("static-access")
    public static void generateNotification(Context context){ 

        mManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        Intent intent1 = new Intent(context,MainActivity.class);
        Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher,"This is a test message!", System.currentTimeMillis());
        intent1.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP| Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        PendingIntent pendingNotificationIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context,0, intent1,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
        notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, "AlarmManagerDemo", "This is a test message!", pendingNotificationIntent);
        mManager.notify(0, notification);
    }
}
```

My Alarm Service:

```
public class MyAlarmService extends Service {

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
        super.onCreate();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId)
    {
        super.onStart(intent, startId);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onDestroy();
    }

}
```

Next Activity:

```
public class NextActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A few things you need to do here. If the user force closes the app, you need to ensure that you start your service with [START_STICKY](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#START_STICKY) so that the service restarts when the app is force closed.

In order to get the Service to start when the user has rebooted their phone, you will need your `BroadcastReceiver` to [receive BOOT_COMPLETED](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5290164/4624156) which will then start the service.

Your service will then set the Alarm as per normal. You will need to store the time of the alarm you want to set somewhere. I use SharedPrefs (`PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());`) but I'm sure there are better methods.

Comment: The code is pretty clear on both links, sorry. Good luck

In case you missed them: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#START_STICKY
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5290141/android-broadcastreceiver-on-startup-keep-running-when-activity-is-in-backgrou/5290164#5290164

Comment: no issues @Larid Thanks for sharing your knowledge :)