# Android timer app

Tags: android, android-timer

Is it anyway possible that when I set a timer, it will still run even if I restart the phone? Like the alarm clock it is still there when I restart the phone. If it is possible can I get the code of it? I really need it.

Comment: The alarm works cause it add a CalendarEvent, for what you want to achieve, you need to calculate when the timer needs to goes on depending on when it it started and add an event, have a look [here](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html)

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can do this but currently I have not the code.
I can give you steps to make your own.

**Steps**

1- Create `CountDownTimer` in your activity

```
            // 10 minutes Timer And 1 Second Delay
            new CountDownTimer(10*30*1000, 1000) {

                public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                    // save `millisUntilFinished` to sharedpreferences
                }

                public void onFinish() {

                    // clear sharedPreferences when it finished
                   //and do whatever you want after finishing the timer here
                }
            }.start();
```

2- Create A `BroadCastReceiver` with `BOOT_COMPLETED` Action start your Timer again with your last saved value from Sharedpreferences

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    //again Start your timer from here

    // Get millisUntilFinished from SharedPreference
    millisUntilFinished = Long.parseLong(getLastSavedValueFromSharedPreferences());

    new CountDownTimer(millisUntilFinished, 1000) {

        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            // save `millisUntilFinished` to sharedpreferences
        }

        public void onFinish() {

            // clear sharedPreferences when it finished
            // and do whatever you want after finishing the timer here
        }
    }.start();
}
```

That's It.

## EDIT

Step 1- Create a `TestActivity.java` class

```
public class TestActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.test_work);

        sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("MySharedPref", MODE_PRIVATE);
        editor = sharedPreferences.edit();

        startTimer();

    }

    private void startTimer() {

        // 10 min Timer
        new CountDownTimer(10*60*1000, 1000)
        {
            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

                editor.putLong("millisUntilFinished", millisUntilFinished);
                editor.commit();
            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {

                editor.clear();
                // Do your work Here
            }
        }.start();
    }
}
```

Step 2- Create `BootReceiver.java` class

```
public class BootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(final Context context, final Intent intent) {

        sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences("MySharedPref", context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        editor = sharedPreferences.edit();

        startTimer();
    }

    private void startTimer() {

        // get remaining time from sharedPreferences
        long millisUntilFinished = sharedPreferences.getLong("millisUntilFinished", 0);

        // 10 min Timer
        new CountDownTimer(millisUntilFinished, 1000)
        {
            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

                editor.putLong("millisUntilFinished", millisUntilFinished);
                editor.commit();
            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {

                editor.clear();
                // Do your work Here
            }
        }.start();
    }
}
```

Step 3- Register your Receiver in `AndroidManifest.xml` file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

<!--Register your BootReceiver here-->
    <receiver android:name=".receiver.BootReceiver">
        <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Here is the complete code. You just need to follow the steps.

Comment: So will the timer still run even if I restart the phone? Like for example I have 10 mins in timer then I only have 5 mins left then I restart the phone. Will the timer be still at 5 Mins?

Comment: And also can you elaborate about the sharedPreferences part? It's the only thing that I have not understood from the code.

Comment: @GlennMichaelTorregosa Yes when you restart the phone your Broadcast receiver will called and your timer will start again.
And sharedPreferences is the data storing system. it allows you to store and access your data.

Comment: Here is the best example of sharedPreferences  http://stackoverflow.com/a/23024962/6676466 Try this to store and retrieve your data.

Comment: So, when the phone is already restarted then there is no need to run the app again? It will automatically continue to count down?

Comment: Yes it will automatically run again.
The BroadcastReceiver will handle the action of BOOT_COMPLETED. when you restart the phone the BroadcastReceiver called itself. and we have wrote the code of starting Timer in BroadcastReceiver.
Here is the [BroadcastReceiver Example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5290164/6676466)

Comment: @GlennMichaelTorregosa I have edited My Answer with complete code Please Check it.

Comment: The thing to keep in mind is if the timer should be updated while rebooting. Like what if the timer has 5 min left but the phone is offline for 2 minutes so logically it should continue running with 3 minutes left. If it should continue from 5 minutes this answer is the correct one else I would recommend the comment from @Luca Nicoletti

Comment: Thanks man! I will test your code tomorrow. Hopefully, it will work like a charm