# start service, when device reset

Tags: android, service

I have broadcast receiver

public class StartServiceReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Log.d("TEST", " start");
    context.startService(new Intent(context, MyService.class));
}
```

}

and my manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

<application
    android:name=".AnalyticsApplication"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".Activity.MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".Activity.ListCitiesActivity">
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".Activity.InfoActivity">
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Settings.SettingsActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_settings"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".Activity.DetailActivity"></activity>

    <service android:name=".MyService"/>

    <receiver
        android:name=".StartServiceReceiver"
        android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"
        android:enabled="true">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

</application>
```

but service do not start, when I am starting my device
log Log.d("TEST", " start"); do not show
How can I fix it ?

Comment: Post you full manifest file.

Comment: add to my question

Comment: Probably [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5290141/android-broadcastreceiver-on-startup-keep-running-when-activity-is-in-backgrou?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) will help

Comment: Remove `android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"` from the `<receiver>` element. Beyond that, have you launched your `MainActivity` at least once after installation before rebooting, to bring your app out of the _stopped_ state?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this permission in manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
```

**Update1:** Try to add this one

```
 <receiver
            android:name=".StartServiceReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true"
            android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

Comment: Does log cat show "start" message that you print in onReceive method?