# How do I set device owner to a priv-app as factory defaults?

Tags: android, android-source

I know you can run an adb command to make an app to be a device owner:

```
adb shell dpm set-device-owner com.example.app/.AdminReceiver
```

I have made com.example.app a privileged app. Is there a way that I can set this app up as a device owner **in the ASOP ROM**? So that when the device boots up for the first time or after a factory reset, the app will be automatically provisioned as the device owner.

Due to some limitations, I cannot modify this privileged app. So I'm looking for solutions that can be done outside the app.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're a privileged app, you should have no problem enabling it by default.

You'll need a [boot receiver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5290141/android-broadcastreceiver-on-startup-keep-running-when-activity-is-in-backgrou) (make sure to include the specified permission).

You'll also need to add

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_DEVICE_ADMINS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS_FULL" />
```

Then, inside your boot receiver, you can run this:

```
DevicePolicyManager manager = (DevicePolicyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.DEVICE_POLICY_SERVICE);
manager.setActiveAdmin(
    new ComponentName(context, YourAdminReceiverClass.class),
    true
);
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way that I can set in the ROM instead of changing the app? Due to some limitations, I cannot do it this privileged app.

Comment: You could add a new system service, or hijack one.

Comment: Can you be more specific? or update your answer with more details? appreciate it.

Comment: Just run the code I told you to run in your boot receiver somewhere else. I don't know how to create system services, so I can't help you.