# my app doesn't send any notifications when it's not running (killed)

Tags: java, android, notifications

I have a reminder app that sends a notification according to the time of the item in the listview, the problem is that whenever my phone is rebooted or the app is killed, the app doesn't send any notification.

**Note: The app is offline and local, it doesn't use internet connection, I don't use FCM or and online services for this app.**

Thank you so much for your time.

**Update:**
I'm using a thread that searches for data in the local database, If there are any changes in time in the database compared to the current time, the notification should show, but the notification only shows when the app is running, but when the app is killed it doesn't show.

The app needs to run on android 5+,

Comment: Can you share some code?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Broadcast receiver in order to be notified when Boot Completes. And again start the required services of your app.

For reference, have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5290164).

Comment: I tried the Broadcast receiver but It didn't work. I'm trying to run my app on android 5 and up (android 5,6,7,8,9,10....)

Answer (score 0):

This is because when you are killing the app, the `onDestroy` method gets called. When it's killed, you app is not doing anything. For this you would need a broadcast receiver.

## How to implement broadcast receiver?

1. Create a java class named `TimeBradcastReceiver.java`.
2. Paste this code in the class

   ```
   public class TimeBradcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
       @Override
       public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
           String dateString = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.HOUR) + ":" + Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.MINUTE);
           String hourString = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.HOUR);
           String minutesString = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.MINUTE;
           Log.d("MyBradcastReceiver","i have recieved - " + dateString);
       }
   }
   ```
3. Once you have implemented this code, you need to add this to you manifest inside the `application` tag.

   ```
   <receiver android:name="com.chatverse.free.TimeBroadcastReceiver"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.TIME_TICK"/>
        </intent-filter>
   </receiver>
   ```
4. Add this code to your activity which opens the first.

   ```
   IntentFilter mTime = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_TIME_TICK);
   registerReceiver(new TimeBradcastReceiver(), mTime);
   ```
5. Now you can do the comparison of the dates and hours and show the notification.

###### Note - This receiver will update only when a minute has changed.

Comment: adding in `Mark it as an accepted answer if it helps as it may help others too!` removes value from the answer itself, because it would be irrelevant for everyone reading it in future, but you're welcome to remind OP to accept an answer if they're happy with it with comments

Comment: I tried the AlarmManager but It didn't work. I'm trying to run my app on android 5 and up (android 5,6,7,8,9,10....)

Comment: I have updated my answer. Now it shall work for you

Comment: I tried it, it sends me the time in log every minute, but that only works when the app is running, but if I killed the app, it doesn't work anymore, I added a toast to see it visually, but with no success.

Comment: tried 25+ answers on google but none of them worked. Sorry